# How to convert XML to recordset and vice versa in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, ado.net, recordset

I'm working on a project that still use Visual FoxPro language for data manipulation in some cases. We used to convert DataTables to RecordSet in both directions. But due the necessary changes new demands came up. So, now I'm trying to came up with some new solution how to transfer XML to RecordSet and vice versa?

I'm still junior developer when it comes to C# and asp.net.

I found so many possible solutions written in old frameworks or in VB, but nothing works. Here's some sweet example that I can't implement in C# with newest frameworks and core technology.

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert XML to recordset
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sXML"></param>
/// <returns>Recordset</returns>
public static Recordset recordsetFromXML(string sXML)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sXML))
    {
        // Nothing to convert
        return null;
    }

    // Open an ADO Stream
    var oStream = new Stream();
    oStream.Open(Missing.Value, ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown,
                 StreamOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenStreamUnspecified,
                 "", "");

    // Load the XML string into stream
    oStream.WriteText(sXML, StreamWriteEnum.adWriteChar);
    oStream.Position = 0;

    // Create empty recordset
    var oRecordset = new Recordset();

    // Read the XML stream
    oRecordset.Open(oStream, Missing.Value,
                    CursorTypeEnum.adOpenUnspecified,
                    LockTypeEnum.adLockUnspecified, 0);
    oStream.Close();

    //Return the recordset
    return oRecordset;
}

/// <summary>
/// Convert recordset to XML
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oRecordset"></param>
/// <returns>String</returns>
public static string recordsetToXML(Recordset oRecordset)
{
    string xmlString = "";

    if (oRecordset != null)
    {
        // Load recordset into stream
        var oStream = new Stream();
        oRecordset.Save(oStream, PersistFormatEnum.adPersistXML);

        // Get the XML
        xmlString = oStream.ReadText(oStream.Size);
    }

    return xmlString;
}
```

How can I translate this code?

EDIT: Added simple XML example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="report">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="broj" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ugo_id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="osi_id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="poc_dat" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ist_dat" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ASSIST_CARD" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="iznos" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="ID_STATUST" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="VRSTA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="marka" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="tipmodel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="REG_OZN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="BR_SASIJE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="iznos1" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="stat_id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="zaglavlje">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="zagl_izv8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="naslov_izv" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="podnaslov_izv" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="qser_no" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <report>
    <broj>18-0000001-01</broj>
    <ugo_id>5000000000011</ugo_id>
    <osi_id>5000000000011</osi_id>
    <poc_dat>2017-06-08T00:00:00+02:00</poc_dat>
    <ist_dat>2018-06-08T00:00:00+02:00</ist_dat>
    <ASSIST_CARD>1234567890</ASSIST_CARD>
    <iznos>88.50</iznos>
    <ID_STATUST xml:space="preserve"></ID_STATUST>
    <VRSTA>01</VRSTA>
    <marka>KIA</marka>
    <tipmodel>PRIDE</tipmodel>
    <REG_OZN>RI555RT  </REG_OZN>
    <BR_SASIJE>5454564564564</BR_SASIJE>
    <iznos1>88.50</iznos1>
    <stat_id>18040101</stat_id>
  </report>
  <zaglavlje>
    <zagl_izv1>MORE OSIGURANJE D.D.</zagl_izv1>
    <zagl_izv2>Petra Jurčića 16</zagl_izv2>
    <zagl_izv3>88000 MOSTAR</zagl_izv3>
    <zagl_izv4 />
    <zagl_izv5>SARAJEVO, 03.04.2019</zagl_izv5>
    <zagl_izv6 />
    <zagl_izv7 />
    <zagl_izv8 />
    <naslov_izv>Pregled CA polica u razdoblju: 01.03.2000 - 01.04.2020</naslov_izv>
    <podnaslov_izv />
    <qser_no>CUBIS REPORT 200021-857740081</qser_no>
  </zaglavlje>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Need to see sample of xml input.  If the XML has too may layers of descendants the standard Net Library functions will not work.

Comment: @jdweng i edited my post and added XML example. Usually they don't have many layer, in most cases there is just one. Many tables with their attributes.

Comment: The DataSet method seems to work fine :             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME,XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

Comment: I assume you are using one of the connections strings shown here : https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/.

Comment: @jdweng yes mate, you're correct. But is there any way to bypass DS?

Comment: Yes.  Just use a query or use Entity.  Or use BulkCopy.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.8